# Simple "loop" in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, joomla

I am using Joomla and I want to do a simple "loop" or however it is called...

Explanation:

When using this code:

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$column= $db->loadColumn();
print_r($column);
```

I managed to "print" the following:

> Array ( [0] => 0.75 [1] => 1.10 [2] => 1.50 [3] => 2.20 [4] => 3.00
>   [5] => 4.00 [6] => 5.50 [7] => 7.50 [8] => 11.00 [9] => 15.00 [10] =>
>   18.50 [11] => 22.00 [12] => 30.00 [13] => 37.00 [14] => 45.00 [15] => 55.00 [16] => 75.00 [17] => 90.00 [18] => 110.00 [19] => 132.00 [20] => 160.00 [21] => 200.00 [22] => 250.00 [23] => 315.00 [24] => 355.00 [25] => 400.00 [26] => 450.00 [27] => 500.00 [28] => 560.00 [29] =>
>   630.00 [30] => 710.00

How can I print the values only?
Like this:

> 0.75
>   1.10
>   1.50
>   2.20
>   3.00
>   4.00
>   5.50
>   7.50
>   11.00
>   15.00
>   18.50
>   22.00
>   30.00
>   37.00
>   45.00
>   55.00
>   75.00
>   90.00
>   110.00
>   132.00
>   160.00
>   200.00
>   250.00
>   315.00
>   355.00
>   400.00
>   450.00
>   500.00
>   560.00
>   630.00
>   710.00

Should I use "while", "foreach" or something else?

Since I am an absolute beginner please share the exact full "coding"

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have to use a loop to print values of your array. You can use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for example

```
foreach($column as $key => $val) {
    echo $val . ' ';
}
```

Comment: "$column as $key => $val" can you please explain to me what is the logic of this?

Comment: The parser takes you array and foreach pair of key and values prints them, have a look ti the link i gave you for further information

Answer (score 1):

Its simple:

```
echo implode(" ",$column);
```

Comment: That answers my question, but didn't solve my problem. Since I want to put some html to the values...